# Why does nslookup script give different results?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, nslookup

I try to use name resolution and get IP address of a web site. I used **nslookup** command and use 6'th line of its output. Because I noticed that output of nslookup contains IP address(in IPv4) in 6'th line. My command was :

```bsh
website=<somewebsiteURL>
IP=$(nslookup "$website" | head -n 6 | tail -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2)
```

Also I tried sed command to reach the same goal and used :

```bsh
website=<somewebsiteURL>
IP=$(nslookup "$website" | sed -n 6p | cut -d" " -f2)
```

result was the same, result is unreliable, sometimes worked, sometimes not.

It works correctly but not always. Sometimes it reads the 7'th line, not the 6'th line and fails.

Actually I solved my problem using another approach :

```bsh
website=<somewebsiteURL>
newIP=$(nslookup "$website" | grep "Address: " | head -n 1 | cut -d" " -f2)
```

which gave the correct line and IP address everytime(although it can give more than one IP > [nslookup can return more than one IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513545/nslookup-return-only-ip-address))

Why do the first two codes fail?

Comment: As you notice, the output of nslookup doesn't make a guarantee on line numbers. So, that's why it fails: you're assuming you can assume something about number of lines always being the same, but that's a wrong assumption.

Comment: The `host` output be easier to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep` to parse strings that "looks like" a valid IPv4 addresses :

```
nslookup unix.stackexchange.com | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}[^#]'
151.101.129.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
```

---

Use tool such as `dig`. It can output directly the info you desire without the need for external parsing tool:

```
dig +short A unix.stackexchange.com
151.101.65.69
151.101.129.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.1.69
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a chance to `host` command.
As generally more than one IP can be associated with a host name, you will probably happy with the first one.

```
host -4 cnn.com | sed 1q  | awk '{ print $NF }'
151.101.129.67
```

This seems to be more reliable

`sed 1q` filters out all lines except for the 1st,
`awk '{ print $NF }'` prints out the last field which is IP you want, and
`-4` instructs to use ipV4 address, you probably want that